# Select element only if it's not child of another element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, css-selectors

I'm currently working on a web component repeater, and I'm encountering an issue when I try to mix two repeater in the same element. My HTML is:

```
<company-repeat id="table">
    <table class="selectable" description="Résultats de recherche">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <company-repeat id="table-metadata">
                    <th class="sorting" repeatable>${name}</th>
                </company-repeat>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr repeatable>
                <td>${id}</td>
                <td>${name}</td>
                <td>${surname}</td>
                <td>${registered}</td>
                <td><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-download" title="Télécharger">D</i></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</company-repeat>
```

What I would like to do is generating the thead dynamically according to a list I receive, but the issue is that my code take the first "repeatable" element it found (`this.template = this.querySelector('[repeatable]');`). What I need right now is a selector to specify that I want the first element it found, only if it's not child of another company-repeat.

Is it doable only with a selector or do I have to retrieve them all, check if the element is child of another element and then only set it to my property?

Something like `document.querySelector('!company-repeat > [repeatable]');`would be perfect, but I highly doubt it exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it doable only with a selector...

Sadly not, no. There's no "select X but only if X is not a descendant of Y". (One is tempted by the `:not` pseudoclass, but it only allows simple selectors, not the compound kind we'd need for this.)

> ...or do I have to retrieve them all, check if the element is child of another element and then only set it to my property?

Yes, that's the approach you'll need to use.

Comment: This would apply if by "child" the asker really meant to say "descendant", which happens often, but that doesn't appear to be the case here, at least judging from the use of the > combinator in the example. `:not(company-repeat) > [repeatable]` works.

Comment: @BoltClock: The HTML shows that the `[repeatable]` for a `company-repeat` may well be a non-child descendant (the one for `#table` is a great-grandchild). It's just that that selector example is in error.

Comment: If the asker would spell out which element(s) they want matched, that would be great. For example, if they're interested in the `company-repeat#table > table > tbody > tr[repeatable]`.

Comment: @BoltClock: Seems fairly clear to me, but sure, more detail could be useful.

Comment: I was interested in selecting the element matching its own company-repeater, in this case, the tr[repeatable] was supposed to match the table and the th should match the table-metadata. However, this solution will not work because of the Table element not accepting any custom element in it, the company-repeat is placed outside, breaking this piece of code. I'll have to find a workaround.

Comment: @Sakuto: I was wondering about that, I figured you knew something about web components I didn't (which isn't hard, I haven't gotten into them in any depth) that would let you use them in a table like that. Sorry to hear that's not the case. :-) Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately no, I was struggling for nothing. Time to find another way!

Answer (score 1):

There can be two approaches you can use. consider the example given in snippet where we want to find the first `<p>` element which is not child of `<li>` element

First approach is to find all `<p>` which are not decedent of `<li>` element and display first `<p>` element

```
var allP = $(document).find('p:not(li p)');
    console.log(allP[0]);
```

Second approach is to find all `<p>` element ,iterate over all `<p>` elements and return first `<p>` element whos parent is not `<li>`

```
allP =  $(document).find('p');

    var correctP;

    for(i=0;i<allP.length;i++){
      if($(allP[i]).parents('li').length==0){
        correctP = allP[i];
        break;
      }
    }

    console.log(correctP);
```

Please see the snippet for more details.

```js
 //Here we are printing first p element who's parent is not li   

//first approach
var allP = $(document).find('p:not(li p)');


console.log(allP[0]);

//second approach
allP =  $(document).find('p');

var correctP;

for(i=0;i<allP.length;i++){
  if($(allP[i]).parents('li').length==0){
    correctP = allP[i];
    break;
  }
}

console.log(correctP);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <p>Hello p1</p>
  <li><p>Hello p2</p></li>
  <li><p>Hello p3</p></li>
  <p>Hello p4</p>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why/how this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [this Meta question and its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/215552) for more information.

Comment: I like how this answer basically assumes jQuery is universally active and is all like "pay no attention to the script element behind the curtain." There is a reason the script element is needed at all...

Comment: @BoltClock sorry i did not get you. did i miss something in answer. Happy to receive a feedback

Comment: I was not using jQuery, and to be honest I did not really understand the purpose of this code to help me with my issue. But Thanks anyway for the effort.